# How setup the PL/SQL project in local computer

Tags: plsql

I have already install a PL/SQL software in to my computer

I am new to PL/SQL now I have downloaded a PL/SQL projects from google, which contain a folder call hrd

here is the screen short of folder structure 
[image]

How to run this project to my local computer

Comment: what do you mean run a folder inside sql?

Comment: no nothing to do with php

Comment: how to run the download project to my local computer

Comment: I'm not sure how. PL/SQL is a block structured language. The programs of PL/SQL are logical blocks that can contain any number of nested sub-blocks. I think you should have php to work with server and browser while pl/sql works with the db. or use some server side js like node js. try read [here](http://scientificsentence.net/Databases/plsql_php.html)

Comment: _I have already install a PL/SQL software in to my computer_ Do you mean [Oracle Forms](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/overview/index.html)?

Comment: no ,i have installl a plsql sofware  11g to my computer

Comment: The Oracle Database system utilizes standard SQL as do many other Database systems.  Within Oracle it uses it's own language referred to as `PL/SQL` (Programmed Logic).  Microsoft SQL Server Database also uses standard SQL and just like Oracle has it's own syntax to work with SQL referred to as `T-SQL` (Transact SQL).

Comment: @kumar123 To work with Oracle's PL/SQL code/syntax you need to install Oracle Express (XE).  Download Oracle XE:  https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Whoever told you it was a PL/SQL application was pulling your leg.

Your screenshot contains a directory called FORMS and the top-level directory contains files with suffixes of .fmb and .fmx. Those indicate Oracle Forms input (.fmb) and Forms executable (.fmx) respectively, So what you have is **an Oracle Forms application**.

You can download Forms Builder IDE from the Oracle website. [Find out more](https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/forms/downloads.html).